# LiveData not updating when changing visibility?

Tags: android, data-binding, android-livedata, android-mvvm

MainActivity

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    activityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, 
 R.layout.activity_main)
    mainViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(
        this@MainActivity,
        mainViewModelFactory
    )[MainViewModel::class.java]
    activityMainBinding.viewmodel = mainViewModel
    activityMainBinding.lifecycleOwner =   this

        mainViewModel.fetchBusinessList()
mainViewModel.businessList.observe(this, Observer { items ->
        run {
          mainViewModel.isLoading.value = false
        }
    })
```

MainViewModel

```
class MainViewModel(val repository: MainActivityRepo) : ViewModel() {

val isLoading: MutableLiveData<Boolean> = MutableLiveData()
lateinit var businessList: LiveData<List<Content>>

fun fetchBusinessList() {
    isLoading.value = true
    businessList = repository.getBusinessList()
}
```

Layout

```
    <androidx.core.widget.ContentLoadingProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/clp_fetching"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:visibility="@{viewmodel.isLoading?View.VISIBLE:View.GONE}"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

I had tried `setValue`, `postValue` and also added `LifeCycleOwner` it's not affecting the visibility to false.

Comment: I can't see any `postValue` or visibility related code in your question

Comment: Bro please see the last line, I have tried every option, setting to true is working fine. @VivekMishra

Comment: `VIew.GONE`. I see a upper case mistake with I in view

Comment: Corrected that, that's a typing mistake while copying the question, that's not the issue. @VivekMishra

Comment: try calling executePendingBinding()

Comment: Please read about `NetworkBoundResource` so that you don't end up calling methods like `fetchBusinessList()` from the Activity, which should be internal to the `LiveData.onActive` method.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `executePendingBindings()` manually whenever you change the value of `isLoading`.

Or you can use a custom binding adapter to reach this functionality:

```
@BindingAdapter("mutableVisibility")
fun setMutableVisibility(view: View, visibility: MutableLiveData<Boolean>?) {
    val parentActivity: AppCompatActivity? = view.getParentActivity()
    if (parentActivity != null && visibility != null) {
        visibility.observe(parentActivity, Observer { value -> view.visibility = if(value) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE})
    }
}
```

then in your layout:

```
<androidx.core.widget.ContentLoadingProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/clp_fetching"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        app:mutableVisibility="@{viewmodel.isLoading}"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: In the above code snippet you haven't used `executePendingBindings`

Comment: no, no need. its automatically handle by observing LiveData

Comment: `executePendingBindings()` should use according your implementation not mine

Answer (score -1):

Some  observations regarding the user of ViewModel

You are trying to update a property in the View Model from the Activity, which you should not.

View Model

```
class MainViewModel(val repository: MainActivityRepo) : ViewModel() {

val isLoading: MutableLiveData<Boolean> = MutableLiveData()
lateinit var businessList: LiveData<List<Content>>

fun fetchBusinessList() {
    isLoading.value = true
    businessList = repository.getBusinessList()
}

// This is where you the content of the list would be received
fun onListUpdated(contentList : List<Content>){
    businessList.value = contentList;
    isLoading.value = false;
 }
```

Activity

> ```
> override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
> super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
>     activityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, 
>  R.layout.activity_main)
>     mainViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(
>         this@MainActivity,
>         mainViewModelFactory
>     )[MainViewModel::class.java]
>     activityMainBinding.viewmodel = mainViewModel
>     activityMainBinding.lifecycleOwner =   this
>
>         mainViewModel.fetchBusinessList()
> mainViewModel.businessList.observe(this, Observer { items ->
>         // Update UI Here
>     })
> ```

Comment: "change `val` to `var`" there is no reason to do that